# How to always show dropdown below the trigger

Tags: css, materialize

Using materializecss, I'm having this code:

```
<a class='dropdown-trigger-courseForm filterButton' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Drop Me!<i class="fa fa-angle-down filter"></i></a>
<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Test</span></label></li>
</ul>
```

And this jquery:

```
 $('.dropdown-trigger-courseForm').dropdown({
    coverTrigger: false,
    closeOnClick: false
  });
```

What I want is to show the dropdown **ALWAYS** below the trigger and not only when there is enough room on the viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a height calculation bug or "undesired behaviour" with the materializecss version I'm using. I just changed the height in the javascipt directly in the materializecss javascript file and it is working as I want it now.